# Update Runtime sudo transaction exhausted (Substrate)

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template, extrinsic, weight

I am trying to reimplement one of the Substrate tutorials:

https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/upgrade-a-running-network/

But I am stuck with an issue - where it says to do Scheduler -> Schedule -> sudo transaction to set code with the new runtime version when I try to sign this transaction (scheduled in 20+ blocks from the current block like it says in the tutorial) I am getting the following error:

[image: Screenshot with error on the request page]

When I go to Network -> explorer I see this:

```
sudo.Sudid
A sudo just took place. [result] 
sudoResult: Result<Null, SpRuntimeDispatchError>
Err
DispatchError
Exhausted
```

Full error backlog below:
[image: UP]
[image: MID]
[image: DOWN]

Had anyone faced this before? And how do you solve it?
It is a tutorial and based on demo pre-defined data, so "not enough moneyunits to pay for your gas" shouldn't be an issue, I would imagine.

**UPD:**
The question is specifically about the second part of the Substrate tutorial - where they use Scheduler pallet and sudo query to schedule runtime upgrade. This part:
[image: Using Scheduler pallet instead of unchecked weights]

Answer (score 1):

There was a recent change to the scheduler pallet which makes it now precisely meter its own weight consumption. The tutorial was probably not updated yet.
This leads to a situation where a full block cannot be consumed by a scheduled task anymore, since the scheduler already deduced his own cost from the full block.
The proper solution is to benchmark it, which will happen [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/13192).

The current make-shift solution (which was also applied on Polkadot) is to use `Utility::with_weight`. This call can be used to wrap any other call and explicitly force it to use a specific weight. So instead of consuming a full block, you can force it to consume just 10% to make it work. So instead of sending `System::set_code(…` you send `Utility::with_weight(System::set_code(…`.

On a relay and solo chain this is not of much concern, since the only bad thing would be longer block time for that one block. On a para-chain this could lead to problems if the para-chain misses its block production slot or goes overweight with the block.

Comment: Thanks, Oliver! How can I run Utility::with_weight in Polkadot.JS Substrate portal? (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/sudo interface connected to local node)

Comment: Just select `Utility` and `with_weight` in the link that you posted. Or compose it manually in the `Developer -> Extrinsics` tab In the `Developer::Extrinsic` tab, which needs a running PolkadotJS browser extension. https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frpc.pinknode.io%2Fwestend%2Fexplorer#/extrinsics/decode/0x15001005000204002828

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi, I'm going to test your workaround solution and update the tutorial. However, it isn't clear whether I should remove the scheduler portion altogether for now (**replace** with the utility pallet) or keep the scheduler but **add** the utility pallet as a wrapper around the System `set_code` call.
Can you clarify?

Comment: The `Utility` does not replace the `Scheduler` here. It just wraps around the call to be scheduled. So it is an additive change. Thanks for updating :)

Comment: Hello @OliverTale-Yazdi we have got some serious issue in our mainnet. we are facing this same issue but the thing is our version is polkadot-v0.9.31 in which this utility function is unavailable. and we dont have sudo unchecked weight or anthing. this seems to be like we cant do any RU anymore? any help will be appreciated

Comment: @ImmanuelJohn i responded over here https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/10380 

Answer (score 0):

See this [error from the docs](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/dispatch/enum.DispatchError.html#variant.Exhausted)

> Resources exhausted, e.g. attempt to read/write data which is too large to manipulate.

The FRAME System module sets boundaries on the block length and block weight that these transactions can use. However, the set_code function is intentionally designed to consume the maximum weight that can fit in a block. Forcing a runtime upgrade to consume an entire block prevents transactions in the same block from executing on different versions of a runtime.

Instead of `sudo` pick the extrinsic `sudoUncheckedWeight` from the pallet `sudo` and call from there the `setCode` extrinsic.
This setting allows for a block to take an indefinite time to compute to ensure that the runtime upgrade does not fail.

From the docs:

> The **sudo_unchecked_weight** function is the same as the sudo function except that it supports an additional parameter to specify the weight to use for the call. This parameter enables you to work around resource accounting safeguards to specify a weight of zero for the call that dispatches the set_code function.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I've already done that before (sudoUncheckedWeight method) and it worked. 
I wasn't precise, the question was specifically about the second part of the tutorial where they use Scheduler pallet to schedule a runtime upgrade.
That part involve sudo query and cause block exhaustion.

Comment: If it is like you say, does it mean that runtime upgrade may need more than one block to be executed?
How would I schedule that?