# No way to do a runtime-upgrade after we upgraded our mainnet chain to version 0.9.31 version

Tags: weight, runtime-upgrade, frame-system

Recently in [Ternoa mainnet](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fmainnet.ternoa.network#/explorer) we performed a RU(runtime upgrade) to upgrade our versions to `polkato-v0.9.31`. In system pallet substrate have introduced new extrinsic `set_code` in this version which consumes `max_block_weight` which is not allowing us to do any RU from this version.

When we checked these [answers](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/6940/427) there are broadly two options to resolve this issue to perform a RU using a `sudo_unchecked_weight` or `utility -> with_weight` function to override the weight. but `0.9.31` version's utility pallet doesn't have `with_weight` function and in our chain we don't have sudo pallet. So this is becoming a serious problem for us. ANY HELP WILL BE APPRECIATED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is still a way to do a runtime upgrade by using `System::SetStorage` which seems to be present in your runtime.
The weight of that should be rather low and you can overwrite the [`:code`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a93858a8d80de838e54d286a820ea29d1a353746/primitives/storage/src/lib.rs#L195) key.
It is very hacky since no event or log will be deposited, but besides that it should work i think. Please test it locally first with chopsticks or another way to ensure that it will not make the situation worse.

Comment: Thanks for putting some lights. Can you let me know how to use this System.set_storage()?

Comment: OMG this worked like a charm, thank you